# ignore duplicated rows in database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a csv file wich I have imported in a database in phpmyadmin, I need to write to a file a new csv file but ignoring duplicated emails, for example if my query finds these two rows :

```
41  Alain   Aiseng  a.as@gmail.com  DL MCI    

42  Alain   Aiseng  a.as@gmail.com  LNKD 05 14
```

BOTH rows should be ignored in my new csv output. What should be the SQL query for this ?

Comment: Probably not a great idea to publish Alain's email address here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate a query for this (and then save the results to a file).  The query is:

```
select t.*
from table t
group by name, email
having count(*) = 1;
```

The columns `name` and `email` correspond to whichever columns hold `Alain Aiseng` and `a.as@example.com`.

Note that this uses a MySQL feature where column names do not have to be in the `group by` for an aggregation query.  This is one case where this feature is totally safe to use, because the `having` clause specifies that only one row matches the condition.

Comment: It's not a "feature" that is good to rely on and it just comes back to bite people - there are numerous question on SO precisely because of this. Use a sane aggregate (or omit the non-grouped columns) instead of this "magic".

Answer (score 3):

```
       select * from table 
       where email not in
       (select email from table group by email having count(*)>1)a;
```